# How to normalize brightness of individual images (post-processing) for a stop motion movie?

Tags: post-processing, software-recommendation, brightness, automation, stop-motion

When creating a stop motion movie we need take a lot of pictures to build the movie.

But after we took the pictures, we have a problem: the brightness and contrast varies between pictures.

What kind of tool can we use to normalize these levels? For example, if we decide that a picture of a defined scene is a good one, how we can automatically, for all pictures taken, normalize the brightness (and contrast) to be compatible with this predefined good picture?

A solution using a free or open source tool would be better for us. Or a script than we can run on a folder, for example. The stop-motion aims to encourage the people ride bicycles.

But if there is a paid solution, we would like to know too.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Some frames and example video could be found in this [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B11O4VAGKGVofi1RYmFXQjJGWlNxeS1lb3VyNE9nNDk2ZGpZWnhFNlB1c1Z4VVE5SWFNb0k&usp=sharing).

Comment: How many frames do you need to correct? (ish)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
http://www.granitebaysoftware.com/products/productgbd.aspx

It claims to do what you need (Although I have no experience with it)
by normalising a sequence as either an Adobe plugin (Premiere or After Effects) or as a standalone application.

Comment: Could be interesting if it works on masked sections in affter effects. :o)

Answer (score 0):

**Use full-manual mode** to lock in the aperature, time, and iso.  If you let the camera choose, they will be differences not just in brighness (easy to fix) but perspective and noise.

Comment: Thanks about the comment. The truth is we already done this, but the studio is not a professional one, so some other lights that we not control unfortunally messed the things a little. With a time limitation, we will can not re-record everything, but we need to fix the brightness of each image that we have. So we are looking for a solution that can fix the brightness after we have a brightness distortion, instead of a technique to avoid this problem. Do you know something that can help us? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You ought to update the question.  If I understand you, you did use a fixed set of settings on the camera, but the lights changed?

Answer (score 0):

Full manual, and of course, fixed lighting that does not vary.

Comment: How would one go about making sure that the lighting does not vary?

Comment: Why would it change? Is the lamp flickering? I would not expect it to change during the working session if nobody moves anything. And tape marks help in case somone trips over a stand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The exposure is not the problem. The exposition on the inside of the elevator is the same.

The problem is that you blocked the exterior light!

The only option I see is that you manually adjust not all the image, but some zones, masking them.

Use this program: http://www.gimp.org/

You will need to have one photo as a reference and the other modified but only in the exterior area, and probably the back of the guy.

I'm afraid you need to make adjustments "by eye".